# codecommitのリポジトリをcloneしようとすると403エラーが出る。

Tags: aws

codecommitのリポジトリをcloneしようとすると403エラーが出ます。

cloneしようとしている環境にはaws configureで（adminaccess）アクセスキーを付与 しています。

clone時には自身の使っているAWSのIAMユーザのユーザ名・PWを使っています。

それでも403エラーが出ます。

何が理由でcodecommitに弾かれてしまうのでしょう？

エラー文

```
Cloning into 'hogehoge1'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/hogehoge1/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 0):

マネージドコンソールでIAMユーザ画面に入ってcodecommit用ユーザを作ることで解決。